# About the Input in a NN

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

So i am new to NN and i'm trying to go deep and apply to my subject. I would like to ask: the input of the NN can it be 2 or more values for example-> the measurement of a value, distance and time? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have more than 1 value as your input.  By my experience typically you're entering in these values as an array of values.  Here is some example code from tensorflow: https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/keras_example

In this example you see 784 inputs, each input is one of the pixels in the 28x28 greyscale image.

Comment: instead of a pixel of an image, can the node of a input layer to be an image?

Comment: Normally your inputs are whatever thing that comes as a 0-1 value. Exceptions, like using words as inputs, do behind-the-scenes work. For examples, with words we actually translate them into vectors, so that for each word we have many input neurons (a bit like converting a word into a list of pixels, if you will).

Comment: @Pablo and then each value in the vector works as input to the nodes of the input layer? Could we use for a example for each image  first a convolution NN and the output of it to be used in another CNN?

Comment: Each value in the vector is the input to a node in the input layer, yes. (The input layer has 3D, one for each word, one for each value in the word vector, and then the batch to process examples in parallel).

Of course you can feed the output of a convolutional layer to another convolutional layer (convolution + activation + batch norm or whatever the convolutional block includes). This is, in fact, how most CNN-based architectures work.

Comment: @Pablo So if have train input data like [ [1,2,3],[11,22,33],[5] ] whose output is a value 1 for example or cat, each node of the input layer will be what?

Comment: What do those numbers represent?

Comment: @Pablo displacement, time and distance from source

Comment: Sorry, that's still too vague. And it is not encouraged to have lengthy off-topic conversations like this! I would recommend that you post a more detailed question, probably in https://ai.stackexchange.com/